# in round() function, second thing after number to be rounded is negative what will be output

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT ROUND(455.23456,-3)
  FROM dual;


SELECT ROUND(455.23456,-3)
  FROM dual;
```

this is what i tried, and i don't know what to expect

Comment: [ROUND (number)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1): ROUND returns n rounded to integer places to the right of the decimal point. If you omit integer, then n is rounded to zero places. If integer is negative, then n is rounded off to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

[`ROUND(value, precision)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1) will round to the nearest 10<sup>-precision</sup>.

So:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(455.23456,-3) FROM DUAL;
```

Will round to the nearest 10<sup>-(-3)</sup> = 10<sup>+3</sup> = 1000 and will output:

| ROUND(455.23456,-3) |
| --- |
| 0 |

Since 455.23456 is closer to 0 than 1000.

And:

```
SELECT ROUND(455.23456,-2), ROUND(455.23456,-1) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ROUND(455.23456,-2) | ROUND(455.23456,-1) |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 460 |

(Rounding to the nearest 100 and 10 respectively.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tov4eNIR)